# Declare function that returns a string in header file

Tags: c++, header-files

How do you declare a function that returns a string in the header file, so it can be used by other *.cpp files.

For example the code bellow does not compile with the following errors:

Source.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

string MyFunc();
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Source.h"

using namespace std;
string MyFunc()
{
   string str;
   return str;
}
```

Errors

```
Error   1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'MyFunc'  4   1
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   4   1
Error   3   error C2872: 'string' : ambiguous symbol    5   1
Error   4   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'MyFunc'  5   1
Error   5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   5   1
Error   6   error C2086: 'int string' : redefinition    5   1
Error   7   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   6   1
Error   8   error C2872: 'string' : ambiguous symbol    7   1
Error   9   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'str' 7   1
Error   10  error C2065: 'str' : undeclared identifier  7   1
Error   11  error C2065: 'str' : undeclared identifier  8   1
```

If I replace `string` with `char*`, it compiles with no errors.

Comment: you forgot `std::`, string is declared inside a namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
std::string MyFunc();
```

You'll need to add the `std::` prefix unless you use the namespace. Generally you might as well prefix it to avoid conflict with your own classes.